# Is there a search engine api that allow me to see the popularity of searches?

Tags: search, search-engine, keyword

I have some text.

Is there is any api which can tell me the the *popularity* of searches for that text in popular search engines such as google, yahoo, etc.

i.e. how it ranking when compared to all other words and searches

Comment: What do you mean when you say "popular search terms from that text"?

Comment: The term which have high weight on Internet.

Comment: Made much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use this:  https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

It's google search API.

If you want a custom solution pay someone to do it.